# Tension of String Connecting Two Objects

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, string-theory, free-body-diagram

I believe the way you find tension in a string connecting 2 objects is by using Newton's Second Law on the object which the tension points to. But I am not completely sure how you would find the tension if the object is not accelerating. Does this mean there is no tension force?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two, equal but opposite forces at each end of the string, there will be no acceleration. Think about the game of tug of war. You have persons at each end of the rope pulling with equal but opposite forces so there is no acceleration of the rope.The sum of the ***external forces*** on the rope is zero. But tension is an ***internal force***. You know its there because if you cut the rope, the contestants will go flying. So do a free body diagram. Cut the rope at one end eliminating one group of contestants. You need to replace them with the force necessary to maintain equilibrium. That’s the tension in the string.

Hope this helps.